# How to pass Decoded Parameter in document.createElement("input") JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The Below code passes required parameter to value but send URI encoded parameters like **Page=2%26range%3D0.00Mb%2BTO%2B14.00Mb%26file_type%3DDOC%26file_type%3DDOCX**  but howto send decoded parameter value like **Page=2&range=0.00Mb TO 14.00Mb&file_type=DOC&file_type=DOCX**

```
var para_wotext="";
var com_para=location.search.substring(1).split("&");
$.each(com_para, function( index, value ) { 
    if(((value.indexOf("cores")) < 0) && ((value.indexOf("textSearch")) < 0) )
    {
        para_wotext+="&"+value; 
    }
});
console.log("para_wotext"+para_wotext);
```

prints in console as :
**2&range=NONE&file_type=PDF&file_type=XLS** which is correct

```
if(!document.getElementById("search-form").Page) 
{
    var hidden = document.createElement("input");
    console.log(hidden);
    hidden.type = "hidden";
    hidden.name = "Page";
    hidden.value = pageNum+decodeURIComponent(para_wotext).toString();//passing decoded parameter  
    var f = document.getElementById("search-form");
    f.appendChild(hidden);
    console.log(f);

}
f.submit()
```

but by Calling f.submit() the submitted form gets prameters as **Page=2%26range%3D0.00Mb%2BTO%2B14.00Mb%26file_type%3DDOC%26file_type%3DDOCX**

Comment: What is your issue exactly?

Comment: That’s just standard URL-encoding … Not really clear what you are trying to achieve here, what do you mean by “the created url”?

Comment: If you are trying to pass GET parameters along with the form to the next page, by putting them into hidden input fields - then you need to create one hidden field for each parameter.

Comment: i Need the URL to be like &Page=2&range=NONE&file_type=PDF&file_type=XLS which the js document.create creates a from submit with the wrong URL-encoding as &Page=2%26range%3DNONE%26file_type%3DPDF%26file_type%3DXLS

Answer (score 0):

if you want to decode Data then use this one where Page is your data

```
var Page ='2%26range%3D0.00Mb%2BTO%2B14.00Mb%26file_type%3DDOC%26file_type%3DDOCX';
var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(Page);
```

Comment: Hi Praveen i have already passed such as `hidden.value = pageNum+decodeURIComponent(para_wotext).toString();` which is equivalent to   `document.getElementById("search-form").namedItem("Page").value = pageNum+decodeURIComponent(para_wotext).toString();`